# ¿Cómo marcar un producto como seleccionado con JQUERY?

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy creando una página en la que puedas seleccionar productos para poder agruparlos en lista de objetos. Necesito deshabilitar el evento click una vez esté marcado como seleccionado.

Cuando seleccione un producto de la lista lo clono en otro div distinto, pero al mismo tiempo quiero resaltarlo como un producto seleccionado pero no sé la forma.

De momento tengo esto:

### Función maquetar

```
function maquetar_datos(data) {
            $('.resultado').empty();
            $('.resultado').append('<h2>Resultado</h2>');
            if(data.length != 0){
                productos = '';
                $.each(data,function(index,value){
                    productos += '<div class="producto-tendencia" style="background:url('+ value.foto +') no-repeat center center; background-size:cover;" producto=' + value.producto +'></div>';
                });
            }else{
                productos = '<div class="resultado-vacio text-center">Esta búsqueda no tiene resultados.</div>';
            }
            $('.resultado').append($(productos));
        };
```

### Búsqueda AJAX

```
        $(document).on('change','#cat_padre',function(e){
            filtro_padre(e.target.value);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/obtener_productos_tendencia/',
                data:{'cat_padre':e.target.value,
                    'color':$('#id_color').val(),
                    'marca':$('#id_marca').val()
                },
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data){maquetar_datos(data)}
            })
        });
```

### Guardar Producto

```
    $(document).on('click','.producto-tendencia',function(e){
            producto = $(e.target);
            producto.unbind('click');
            $('.productos-guardados').append(producto.clone());

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estas agregando el manejador de evento en `document`, cuando haces:

```
producto.unbind('click');
```

No hay ningun manejador que remover, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar una clase para discriminar por codigo cuando se debe o no realizar el clonado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.producto-tendencia', function(e) {
  producto = $(e.target);
  if (!producto.hasClass("selected")) {
    producto.addClass("selected");
    $('.productos-guardados').append(producto.clone());
  }
});
```

```css
.container .producto-tendencia {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container .selected {
  color: green;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="container">
  <li class="producto-tendencia">1</li>
  <li class="producto-tendencia">2</li>
  <li class="producto-tendencia">3</li>
  <li class="producto-tendencia">4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="productos-guardados">
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ahora a la caja duplicada ¿puedo añadirle un nuevo evento click para hacer justo lo contrario?, es decir, eliminarlo del div seleccionados y a la original quitarle la clase selected

Comment: @fdelgado claro, el código seria similar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadirle una clase .selected o similar con...

```
.selected{
pointer-events:none;
}
```

...para bloquear la interaccion y añadirle lo que quieras para resaltarlo, un border, bajar la opacity, etc.